# How to have another token format than JWT in Keycloak?

Tags: jwt, token, keycloak

Is it possible to have another token format than JWT with Keycloak? 
Keycloak always sends JWT token but I clearly don't want that JWT format. Is it possible to have an `Opaque token` or other format with keycloak?

Thanks

Comment: Keycloak also supports SAML - is that what you're looking for?  Do you want to make up a new token format?

Comment: @stdunbar I don't want using SAML, as JWT is formatted we can use tools like https://jwt.io to get information about users. I would like to prevent that using `Opaque token` and token introspection to validate my tokens. But for now I don't see how to do that with Keycloak

Comment: @stdunbar For more information about token introspection  For more information about token introspection https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/token-introspection-endpoint/

Comment: I agree with you. **Opaque token format** is what I'm missing when using Keycloak. A Node.js OIDC Provider library called oidc-provider has opaque format and [use that by default](https://github.com/panva/node-oidc-provider/blob/main/docs/README.md#formats).

Comment: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/9713#discussion-3819165

Answer (score 1):

I found below links where it says its not implemented and under ongoing discussion/implementation.

1. https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/use-opaque-tokens/3065
2. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/9713#discussion-3819165

Comment: I recently migrated from Keycloak to Spring Authorization Server which is a bit easier to customize.

Comment: Oh great, thanks for letting us know @akuma8 , will sure try it